# He could scarcely provide a more striking contrast to

Tags: meaning

> Sandeep Mathrani starts as the office-rental firm’s chief executive today. **He could scarcely provide a more striking contrast to WeWork’s founder and ousted boss, Adam Neumann.** With no prior experience in the industry, Mr Neumann built WeWork’s valuation to a notional $47bn, largely on the strength of his charisma and vision. His erratic behaviour and the revelation of the company’s out-of-control finances last autumn, however, wiped out most of WeWork’s value and led to the cancellation of its initial public offering. Mr Mathrani, however, is a seasoned executive from Brookfield Properties, a large property-investment firm. His hiring signals that WeWork’s primary backer, SoftBank, wants to turn the loss-making, tech-focused company into a profitable lessor of office space. Any extra value he can squeeze out of WeWork would be welcome to the Japanese tech-investment firm. It has already lost more than $4bn on its stake in the office-space upstart.

---

scarcely : almost no

a more striking contrast to : unlike

What does the sentence mean, the current boss is similar to the previous one?

Comment: No - it's the complete opposite. If something could ***scarcely / hardly*** be true, that means it would be ***rare / difficult*** for it to be true (effectively, there's ***no chance*** of it being true). So in your context, Mathrani is ***so*** different to Neumann that it would be ***impossible** for him to be any **more** different* than he actually ***is.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*He could scarcely* is an idiom meaning *There is hardly any way that he could* i.e. *He can't*.

But because of the *more*, this has the opposite effect from what you might at first think:

> *He could scarcely provide a more striking contrast*
>
> = *There is no way he could provide a more striking contrast*
>
> = *He provides the most striking contrast possible*
>
> = *He is as different is it is possible to be*.